# Openbox - multiple commands separated with & for one keypress

Tags: openbox, rc

I am trying to configure Openbox's **rc.xml** file in order to manipulate my soundcards with one keypress. Because I have multiple sound cards on my system I have to manipulate multiple sinks at once so I use multiple commands separated with **&** like this:

```
    <keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolumen">
   <action name="Execute">
     <command>pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.multichannel-output +5% & pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo +5% & pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 +5%</command>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

For some reason this won't work in rc.xml. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put the commands into a shell script, make that script executable and then uses this script as the command.

```
<command>/usr/local/bin/volume_up</command>
```

The contents of `/usr/local/bin/volume_up`

```
#!/bin/sh
pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.multichannel-output +5% &
pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo +5% &
pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 +5%
```

and make it executable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/volume_up
```

The reason is that Openbox is not executing the contents of the command element in a shell instead it tries to execute it directly.

From the [documentation for `<command>`](http://openbox.org/wiki/Help:Actions#Execute):

> A string which is the command to be executed, along with any arguments
>   to be passed to it. The "~" tilde character will be expanded to your
>   home directory, but no other shell expansions or scripting syntax may
>   be used in the command unless they are passed to the sh command. Also,
>   the & character must be written as & in order to be parsed
>   correctly.  is a deprecated name for .

Another benefit is that you can rewrite the script to also be able lower the volume

```
#!/bin/sh

change_volume() {
    pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.multichannel-output "$1"
    pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo "$1"
    pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 "$1"
}

main() {
    case "$1" in
      up)
         change_volume +5%
         ;;
      down)
         change_volume -5%
         ;;
     *)
         printf "volume <command>\n"
         printf "          up \n"
         printf "         down\n"
    esac
}

main "$@"
```

This would be saved under `/usr/local/bin/volume` and would be use like this

```
<command>/usr/local/bin/volume up</command>
<command>/usr/local/bin/volume down</command>
```

Comment: This is a possible fix, but not exactly what I need.

Comment: @71GA What is it that you need?

Comment: @71GA I added the link to the documentation for `<command>` and the quote. It mentioned that you can call `sh -c` to do such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not mind the order and the fact that all of these will be executed more or less at once you can do:

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolumen">
   <action name="Execute">
     <command>pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.multichannel-output +5%</command>
   </action>

   <action name="Execute">
     <command>pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo +5%</command>
   </action>

   <action name="Execute">
     <command>pactl set-sink-volume alsa_output.usb-Focusrite_Scarlett_2i4_USB-00.analog-surround-40 +5%</command>
   </action>
</keybind>
```

Comment: This is also a good suggestion! But in my case the order of commands matters.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a bind which increase/decrease volume for all components, this way you will have sure that the wanted component will be affected, if want to make some component disabled just mute it.

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>bash -c "pactl list | grep -oP 'Sink #\K([0-9]+)' | while read -r i ; do pactl -- set-sink-volume $i +3% ; done"</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
<!--  decrease volume  -->
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>bash -c "pactl list | grep -oP 'Sink #\K([0-9]+)' | while read -r i ; do pactl -- set-sink-volume $i -3% ; done"</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be cleaner and shorter for your use case:

```
<keybind key="XF86AudioLowerVolume">
 <action name="Execute">
  <command>sh -c "pactl list sinks | grep 'Sink #' | cut -d'#' -f2 | xargs -I@ pactl -- set-sink-volume @ -2000"</command>
 </action>
</keybind>
<keybind key="XF86AudioRaiseVolume">
 <action name="Execute">
  <command>sh -c "pactl list sinks | grep 'Sink #' | cut -d'#' -f2 | xargs -I@ pactl -- set-sink-volume @ +2000"</command>
 </action>
</keybind>
```

It will list all the sinks and for each increase/decrease the volume. For example when you have jack or bluetooth speakers connected there will be multiple. This is exactly the setup that I am using.